# IEditableCollectionView loses selection on CommitEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, observablecollection

I have `CollectionViewSource` in which dates grouped by years and months. Dates are displayed in `TreeView` (accurately in `RadTreeView`).

The target is to change selected date without recreating the view (do not call `Refresh` method).

To do this I implemented `IEditableObject` in date view model and changed date so:

```
var selectedDate = SelectedDate;

var editableCollectionView = Dates.View as IEditableCollectionView;
if (null != editableCollectionView && !editableCollectionView.IsEditingItem)
{
    editableCollectionView.EditItem(selectedDate);
    selectedDate.Date = dt.Date;
    editableCollectionView.CommitEdit();
}
```

But in this case `TreeView` lost selection and I need to select "selected item" again that leads refreshing data bounded to selected date.

How can I solve this issue? Perfectly using `MVVM` way.

**UPDATE:**

If date is alone in group, changing date causes collapsing item which contains it.

**UPDATE 2:**

May be I shouldn't use SelectedDate property and work only with IsSelected and IsExpanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage MVVM for Tree View Item.

Include two writeable properties in your item level class (which serves as the data context to your individual tree view item)

1. IsExpanded
2. IsSelected

Have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented and property changed notification raised in the setter of the above two properties.

Now at `TreeViewLevel` have a Style that binds these properties.

```
 <TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    ....
 </...>
```

This way the expansion and selection is maintained on the tree view as long as it is maintained in the tree view item's data context.

**Now remember that expanded states can be true for multiple items but selection state true is applicable for only one item along the entire tree view.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this way. But how parent view model to know if child's property IsSelected changed to true? I only could suggest to use EventAggregator from Prism. Is it right way?

Comment: I dont understand, are you saying that your parent has an expanded branch and one of its deep child which is selected, is visible. Now you do some edits on the items source but refresh removes the expansion and selection? Then the above solution is the perfect solution for such situation. Coz unless the whol branch from your expanded parent to the selected child is intact in its data context, the bracn will stay in its exact state of expansion and selection.

Comment: Parent view model is a view model containing all dates. And it need to has selected date property. When selected date changes, I load data bounded to it. See my other question to undestand data structure: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6869958/381804. All that I need: On the left tree of dates. On the right: data bounded to selected date. When I change date in the tree - reload data. When I change date from data using DatePicker - change date in tree.

Comment: Are you using `DateTime` class as tree view item level data context? :(... The suggestion to add `IsSelected` \ `IsExpanded` was in this DateTime class... but thats not possible unless you write a wrapper ... something like `public class MyDateTime : DateTime, INotifyPropertyChanged` and in that class add `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded`.

Comment: Wrapper exists. It is DayWorkInfoViewModel. It also contains Year and Month properties for grouping. WorkViewModel contains ObservableCollection of DayWorkInfoViewModel as field and CollectionViewSource as property and also SelectedDayWorkInfo as notify property bounded to TreeView.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I totally removed SelectedDAte property and operate only IsSelected and IsExpanded. And it works fine.